# Internet cafe with Wi-Fi in Hohhot, China?

Tags: china, internet, power, wifi, hohhot

This is my second time in Hohhot/Huhhot/Huhehaote, the capital of Inner Mongolia, China. I've been here one week this time.

But despite many scouting missions I seem to be unable to find what I think of as a regular Internet cafe or cafe with free Wi-Fi.

A place that provides somewhere to sit, power sockets, and a Wi-Fi signal you can connect to. Typically you pay for coffees and snacks but not for online time or megabytes.

Now that I know the characters I have been able to find many "Internet bars" `网吧`. But they never have Wi-Fi and their computers only ever have a very limited version of Windows with a very limited version of Internet Explorer 6. The majority of modern websites, including Stack Exchange are not usable from them.

I'd prefer a cosy place that has food as well as hot drinks, but really I'm interested to know if there's any place at all with Wi-Fi and electricity. I'm right near the University where things like this would usually be.

(For comparison, such places are trivially easy to find in Seoul, and even common in Ulaanbaatar!)

Comment: I've asked [a related question about how to find such places generally in China](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22014), but this question is specifically about finding one in this provincial capital city.

Comment: I wonder if it made sense to ask how to find something like this by entering the correct Chinese search term into a search engine?

Comment: The only search term I have been able to find is "网吧", which leads to the places full of smoking network gamers on PCs with only IE6 and no Wi-Fi...

Comment: That's why I am suggesting you to ask a question somewhere what to enter into google to find the right thing :)

Comment: Well I got 网吧 from Wiktionary as the only term offered for "Internet cafe". I guess because it's the cultural equivlanet. But I'm holding out that they also have some "western style" ones too which may also get called 网吧. I just went on another scouting mision and found two cute cosy looking place, both closed probably on a New Year's break. One was called "Maggie's Kitchen". There's at least one large pub/bar called "Friday" which you can't see into from outside, and a big expensive-looking chain called Ming Tien Coffee Language, which I'm trying to find out more about on the the net.

Comment: Sometimes places in China with plug in only connectuons will let you plu a laptop in in place of one of their PCs. Depending on how they are set up this may or may not work. I've done this with success from a few places in Asia, but I'd expect it to not work if they were running some of the more hand holding internet cafe systems. | *If* you have access to a 'western' site and a tame guru you could set up a system that allowed essentially terminal only remote access using only a crippled browser.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: Actually all of the *wang ba* 's I've found myself in on this trip have been running the exact same internet cafe software, which does seem a very "hand holding" one. I'm not sure if this is just coincidence or an accurate sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chinese Yelp is called Dianping -- the Hohhot section is here:

http://www.dianping.com/huhehaote

1. Search for 咖啡 ("coffee")
2. Click the button that says 总体评价 ("overall rating") to sort the highest rated shops to the top
3. Click the first location, a cafe called 艾乐咖啡屋 ("Ai Le Coffee") on 赛罕区万达广场东区底商26-67号(近万达东巷) ("26-27 East Dishang Rd (cross road: East Wanda Rd) inside Saihan Wanda Plaza")
4. Click the double chevron next to the text 营业时间、餐厅简介、特色等其他信息 ("additional information about this location")
5. Find that 3 people have indicated this place has Wi-Fi: 分类标签：无线上网 (3) ("Tags: Wireless Internet")

Enjoy!

And if this place doesn't suit your fancy, try another on the list :)

Comment: any chance you have an idea for http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22014/how-to-find-places-with-wi-fi-and-electricity-in-china?lq=1 ?

Comment: @MarkMayo just gave it a shot :) hope the answer is helpful

Comment: nice work! [There's one more which could use your speciality](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/21557/101) ;)

Comment: @MarkMayo happy to help! (though this was a tough one, haha)

Comment: What a shame this came in just after I've left Hohhot after nine days there!